# handling events that do not generate alerts in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I'm using Flink CEP and I need to handle even events that do not generate alerts. Please how can I do it?

I'm consuming events from rabbitMq and have defined some patterns. Now what I need to do is to send all the events received in another Queue to a distant API. I'm new at Flink so I followed the example in the documentation. When I try to send them after matching the received events with the patterns defined I only get those how match with the patterns. What I want to do is just to put an attribute to true in my events for example and send them all to the output queue.

```
    public static void cep() throws Exception {
    /**
     * RabbitMQ connection
     */
    final RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
            .setHost(HOST)
            .setPort(PORTS[RD.getValue()])
            .setUserName("guest")
            .setPassword("guest")
            .setVirtualHost("/")
            .build();

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    /**
     * Retrieve data inputEventstream from rabbitMQ
     */
    final DataStream<String> inputEventstream = env
            .addSource(new RMQSource<>(
                    connectionConfig, // config for the RabbitMQ connection
                    "input", // name of the RabbitMQ queue to consume
                    true, // use correlation ids; can be false if only at-least-once is required
                    new SimpleStringSchema())) // deserialization schema to turn messages into Java objects
            .setParallelism(1);
    /**
     * Change DataStream<String> to DataStream<MonitoringEvent> where
     * MonitoringEvent refer to a class which modelize our event.
     */
    DataStream<MonitoringEvent> inputEventStreamClean = inputEventstream.flatMap(new Tokenizer());

    Pattern<MonitoringEvent, ?> warningPattern = Pattern.<MonitoringEvent>begin("start")
            .subtype(MonitoringEvent.class)
            .where(new SimpleCondition<MonitoringEvent>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(MonitoringEvent value) {
                        return Integer.parseInt(value.getAncienneChute())>=CHUTE_GRAVE;
                }
            }).or(new SimpleCondition<MonitoringEvent>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(MonitoringEvent value) {
                        return value.isChaiseRoulante();
                }
            }).or(new SimpleCondition<MonitoringEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(MonitoringEvent value) {
                        return value.isDeambulateur();
                }
            }).or(new SimpleCondition<MonitoringEvent>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(MonitoringEvent value) {
                    return value.isDeambulateur();
            }
            })
            .or(new SimpleCondition<MonitoringEvent>() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter(MonitoringEvent value) {
                    return EntityManager.getInstance().hasCurrentYearFallTwice(value.getIdClient());
            }
            });

    //PatternStream<MonitoringEvent> fallPatternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStreamClean.keyBy("idClient"), warningPattern);
    inputEventStreamClean.print();

    // Create a pattern stream from our warning pattern
    PatternStream<MonitoringEvent> tempPatternStream = CEP.pattern(
            inputEventStreamClean.keyBy("idClient"),
            warningPattern);

    DataStream<FallWarning> warnings = tempPatternStream.select(
            (Map<String, List<MonitoringEvent>> pattern) -> {
                MonitoringEvent first = (MonitoringEvent) pattern.get("start").get(0);
                return new FallWarning(first.getIdClient(), Integer.valueOf(first.getAncienneChute()));
            }
    );

    // Alert pattern: Two consecutive temperature warnings appearing within a time interval of 20 seconds
    Pattern<FallWarning, ?> alertPattern = Pattern.<FallWarning>begin("start");

    // Create a pattern stream from our alert pattern
    PatternStream<FallWarning> alertPatternStream = CEP.pattern(
            //warnings.keyBy("idClient"),
                warnings,
            alertPattern);

    // Generate alert 
    DataStream<Alert> alerts = alertPatternStream.flatSelect(
            (Map<String, List<FallWarning>> pattern, Collector<Alert> out) -> {
                FallWarning first = pattern.get("start").get(0);

                if (first.idNiveauUrgence>=CHUTE_GRAVE && (first.isChaiseRoulante() || first.isDeambulateur() || first.isFracture())) {
                    out.collect(new Alert(first.idClient));
                }
            });

    // Print the warning and alert events to stdout
    warnings.print();

    alerts.print(); // here I can send them to RabbitMq

    env.execute();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. What do you mean by handling? What do you mean by do not generate alerts. Best if you could add some examples. Right now it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I'm consuming events from rabbitMq and have defined some patterns.
Now what I need to do is to send all the events received in another Queue to a distant API.
I'm new at Flink so I followed the example in the documentation.

When I try to send them after matching the received events with the patterns defined I only get those how match with the patterns.

What I want to do is just to put an attribute to true in my events for example and send them all to the output queue.

Comment: `public static void cep() throws Exception {
    //After getting events and defining the patterns...
        DataStream<Alert> alerts = alertPatternStream.flatSelect(
         (Map<String, List<FallWarning>> pattern, Collector<Alert> out) -> {
                    FallWarning first = pattern.get("start").get(0);
                    out.collect(new Alert(first.idClient));             
                });

        // Print the warning and alert events to stdout
        warnings.print();
        alerts.print(); // here I can send them to RabbitMq
        env.execute();
    }`

Comment: Hi @saidIdrissi, please edit and update the original question with the additional details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a Sink to your "alert" DataStream like

```
alert.addSink(new RMQSink<String>(
connectionConfig,            // config for the RabbitMQ connection
"queueName",                 // name of the RabbitMQ queue to send messages to
new SimpleStringSchema()));  // serialization schema to turn Java objects to messages
```

per example at

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/rabbitmq.html